# Unable to run the app in android emulator or motion

Tags: nativescript

I am unable to run the [Groceries](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1) app/tutorial

I have everything up and ready and when I run

```
tns run android --emulator
```

Emulator starts, but o app gets installed. In the terminal I get:

```
    Project successfully prepared

    :config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
        +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets
     {
                  "F0" {
                    dimension "tnscoremoduleswidgets"
                  }
                } }
    :config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
         Creating product flavors include.gradle file in /Users/luka/projects/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/configurations folder...

    :config phase:  pluginExtend
        +applying configuration from: /Users/luka/projects/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/configurations/include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: /Users/luka/projects/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/configurations/tns-core-modules-widgets/include.gradle

    :config phase:  copyAarDependencies

    :config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: /Users/luka/projects/sample-Groceries/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar
    :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :preF0DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
...
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 23.229 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Project successfully built
Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
```

On the emulator I can't see the app :(

NOTE that using genymotion device by running:

```
tns livesync android --watch
```

I have the same issue...

**EDIT:**

- I got it working by changing the emulator device a few times)
- I switched to Genymotion in the end (much faster)

Answer (score 4):

sometimes Android emulator can be a little difficult to get working. I normally use Genymotion. If you use Genymotion, make sure that emulator is open and running before trying to livesync. Is this what you're doing?

Comment: Sorrry for not replying. In the end I got it working by changing the emulator device a few times... And then (in the real end) I switched to Genymotion&Virtualbox ;)